# Would OpenCL be faster than OpenGL for only drawing circles?

Tags: graphics, gpu, opencl

I have a 2D game that, other than the UI, only needs to draw solid-colored circles. The game also already uses OpenCL for calculating physics for the circles (sort of like a particle simulation). The benifits of rendering with OpenCL would be that I don't need to add another library to the mix, and that I don't need to generate a vertex buffer. I'm just not sure if the performance would still be worse than using dedicated graphics libraries like OpenGL and Vulkan, especially considering things like antialiasing and outlines.

Some details that might be important are that there are thousands of the little circles, and they are all the same size. There is already culling for the physics collisions, so each pixel will only have to consider ~10 circles at most. The image below is close to what I'm trying to make ([image source](https://github.com/johnBuffer/VerletSFML-Multithread)):

[image: image of lots of 2d marbles]

The OpenCL approach is theoretically more efficent, but it really comes down to the amount of hardware acceleration that graphics API's use. This is my first project related to the GPU which is why I'm not sure. Mixing the libraries isn't a big concern since I could just rewrite the physics engine as compute shader or something.

Comment: What do you mean using OpenCL for drawing? OpenCL provides a standard interface for parallel computing using task- and data-based parallelism. Have you ever seen any way to "draw with OpenCL"? It is fine to use OpenCL for calculation and OpenGL for drawing. If you mean something else with "drawing with OpenCL", please provide links to SDK.

Comment: @DamirTenishev I just mean running an OpenCL kernel on an image and then copying the image to the screen.

Comment: I never checked this on real code, but I guess the performance will dramatically differ depending on many conditions (amount of circles, amount of memory on GPU, sizes of batches, etc.). I would vote for working through OpenCL, for most real cases it should be faster if the kernels written appropriately. Is is much easier to write correct code with OpenGL than with OpenCL in this case. If the code written correctly OpenCL case should win, but you might be forced to invent some bicycles like drawing circles on image. Why don't you try both options, compare and tell us the story?

Comment: @DamirTenishev of course OpenCL can draw, like any other programming language. And it is super efficient at it. Example: https://youtu.be/pD8JWAZ2f8o

Comment: @ProjectPhysX, for most of programming languages this totally depends on API for drawing. For example, C language doesn't draw unless you use some kind of graphics API or library or directly access the hardware. The same goes to OpenCL, it can read/write textures which can allow drawing, but it doesn't provide API for drawing primitives like circles, boxes, texts, etc. This way or another you will have to reinvent bicycle writing these functions or use Vulkan or some other library. The example you provided (raytracing) is just very texture-friendly, since no primitives involved.

Comment: Many particle systems draw their particles as small circles (rasterized as quads with a fragment shader that makes it a perfect circle). This doesn't seem to be a problem.  My advice to you so far is don't go looking for problems you don't have yet.  Just get coding with a basic approach and optimize later.

Comment: @DamirTenishev I implemented OpenCL rasterization too ;) Why are people so afraid of Bresenham algorithm, it's not that difficult.

Comment: @ProjectPhysX, this already goes to holy wars :) Any way is possible and that's why I suggested to Samuel write both versions, compare and tell us the story. I am not afraid Bresenham's algorithm, I don't like code duplication and bicycle reinvention unless this reinvention is your goal. In which way your proposal different from mine so that we need to argue? :) I suggested to use OpenCL with reservations of possible drawbacks, meanwhile. You suggesting the same. What is the discussion point in frame of the topic? Performance is highly depended on the implementation, as I warned.

Comment: Here is a game demo with 500000 space ships rendered (and computed for battle) in OpenCL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jl68gVsReQk so millions of circles wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Neither is faster in itself. OpenCL can rasterize just as fast as OpenGL, provided you implement the Bresenham rasterization routine for circles yourself. In the end an image is just an integer array. But in OpenCL you can make application-specific optimizations, like fixed-size circles, to beat generic library rasterization algorithms.

The main performance factors are data movement (avoid PCIe copy, have particles in VRAM and render in VRAM), and data layout (structure of arrays for coalesced memory access).

Since you already have the simulation part in OpenCL, I'd advise to go with OpenCL for rendering too, this way you save yourself the trouble of adding another library, and you have better control over optimization.